# array of arrays in js function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was doing some tasks with this function, but for some reason it does not return values as I think it should.

```
function intersection(arrays) {
  return arrays;
}

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20],[15, 88, 1, 5, 7],[1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
```

OUTPUT

```
[5, 10, 15, 20]
```

How can I access all sub-arrays of a main array inside this function?

Comment: You are passing three arguments. Your function accepts only one, so that's the one returned

Comment: Either put the arrays within another array, add more parameters, or use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass array with the bracket [].

```js
function intersection(arrays) {
  return arrays;
}

console.log(intersection([[5, 10, 15, 20],[15, 88, 1, 5, 7],[1, 10, 15, 5, 20]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass multiple arguments to the function. But the function accepts a single argument. That means that the only the first array in the function will be passed.

With the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) you can turn a single parameter into an array of parameters with an indefinite length. This way you can add arrays like the way you're doing.

```js
function intersection(...arrays) {
  return arrays;
}

const result = intersection(
  [5, 10, 15, 20],
  [15, 88, 1, 5, 7],
  [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]
);

console.log(result);
```

Or pass the arrays as a multidimensional array.

```js
function intersection(arrays) {
  return arrays;
}

const result = intersection(
  [
    [5, 10, 15, 20],
    [15, 88, 1, 5, 7],
    [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]
  ]
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest parameters with `Array#flat`.

```js
function intersection(...arrays) {
  return arrays.flat();
}

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20],[15, 88, 1, 5, 7],[1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
```

Answer (score 0):

While I suggest one of the other answers, if you don't want to change the function signature, nor the calling code, you can use `Array.from(arguments)` in the code to get all of the arguments passed.

```js
function intersection(arrays) {
  return Array.from(arguments);
}

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20],[15, 88, 1, 5, 7],[1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
```